# Method taking an Object and any of its superclasses

Tags: java, generics, casting, superclass

To achieve.

A method `signal` should take

1. any **Object `N`**
2. any of the Object's **superclasses `Class<?super N>`**

```
<N>void
signal(N n, Class<?super N> n_super)
{
  /*...*/
}
```

It should be ok to call

```
Object object=new Object();
signal(object, object.getClass());
```

since `Object` **is a super type of `object`**. But calling it gives a **waring**. In IDE words:

IntelliJ (Android Studio)

> Wrong 2nd argument type. Found `Class<? extends Object>`, required: `Class<? super Object>`

Eclipse

> The method `signal(N, Class<? super N>)`
>   is not applicable for the arguments `(Object, Class<? extends Object>)`

Questions.

1. **Can the goal be achieved, the way I have tried**, and if yes,
2. **how can the warning be eliminated**

Comment: According to documentation of [Object#getClass](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass--) "*The actual result type is `Class<? extends |X|>` where `|X|` is the erasure of the static type of the expression on which getClass is called*" so this explains why you got `Class<? extends Object>` instead of `Class<Object>`. But proper solution would require knowing what you really want to achieve here.

Comment: if you want to pass in the super class, then use object.getClass().getSuperclass() instead

Comment: @Pshemo Thanks for your feedback, I agree! Is there a way to eliminate the warning, then?

Comment: @MT756, no, this is not my intention.

Comment: Using `Object.class` should compile just fine.

Comment: @BeUndead, thanks, yes, this is actually a way to consider!

Comment: You could also go _more_ hacky about it and declare your method as `<A, B extends A> void signal(A a, Class<? super B> klass) { /* ... */ }` which should let your original approach to it work.  I wouldn't be surprised if it also let other, unintended cases work though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning my comments into an answer.

Two approaches I can quickly think of:

---

Use `Object.class` directly here.  `signal(object, Object.class);` compiles fine with no warnings on my java version.

---

Change your method signature to something like:

```
<N, M extends N> void signal(N n, Class<? super M> n_super)
```

which should let you call it the way you already are (as in `signal(object, object.getClass());`).

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot for opening my eyes. You all are such a cool community.

Comment: Still, even after trying, I was not able to implement the method the 2nd way... Any tips?

Comment: @Passi: What's stopping you implementing it that way?  [This example](https://ideone.com/RODJIY) shows it in action.

Comment: I agree, this should be possible in theory and would be a quite beautiful solution. Trying this still is not working as it should (neither example nor your 2nd way): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CMu6dOu4oBjTP5IwzEZtlDzJyVvGVcUo/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Passi: Hmm...  I tried this on my JVM at work when I answered and it was fine (and apparently was fine on the one used on the IDEOne example I posted above).  But testing it on my home computer (different OS) it is giving the same error you're seeing (even though my IDE isn't highlighting it _as_ an error).  Perhaps this is a defect/difference between the java versions for different OSes.  Sorry :/.

Comment: Tried this again on java 11 and java 14 (release candidate).  Worked fine on both.  What java version are you using?

Comment: java -version and System.getProperty("java.version"), tell me, I have openjdk version "11.0.6" 2020-01-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.6+10-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu119.10.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.6+10-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu119.10.1, mixed mode, sharing)

Answer (score 0):

use something like this:

```
Object object=new Object();
Class c = object.getClass();
signal(object, c);
```

Comment: The warning will now be now about type safety, but thanks!

Comment: @passi rhetorical: How can taking an object and its superclasses be safe in any situation?

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 ^^